# How to Delete single line from ArrayList in Android Canvas?

Tags: java, android, canvas, arraylist

I want to Delete single line from android canvas using ArrayList m not able to delete it

whenever i touch on that circle point i want to delete that line

```
            if (line_cir > 2) {
                if (touchedline != null) {
                    dr_count = 2;

                    if ((Math.abs(touchedline.stopX - endX) < 40) && (Math.abs(touchedline.stopY - endY) < 40)) {

                        lines.remove(line_c);

                            st_count=1;
```

thanks For in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer.

i have found my answer i just have to change the .

```
lines.remove(touchedline);                         
line_cir=0;
```